# Sharepoint: Trying to get the latest ID

Tags: jquery, web-services, sharepoint, caml

I am using a web service and am trying to return the highest **ID** number from the **Posts** list with viewname **{B9212691-1AF1-41AF-9DA7-6073ADDB091B}**.
So far I have the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var soapEnv =
            "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                <soapenv:Body> \
                     <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                        <listName>Posts</listName> \
                        <viewName>{B9212691-1AF1-41AF-9DA7-6073ADDB091B}</viewName> \
                    <View> \
                        <Query> \
                                 <OrderBy> \
                                <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /> \
                             </OrderBy> \
                        </Query> \
                    <RowLimit>1</RowLimit> \
                    </View> \
                    </GetListItems> \
                </soapenv:Body> \
            </soapenv:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            url: "_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            complete: processResult,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
    });


    function processResult(xData, status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
            var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_ID") + "</li>";
            $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
        });
    }


</script>

<ul id="tasksUL"/>
```

This just returns the IDs of the view in SharePoint.
Any ideas how to get just the highest ID number?

Answer (score 0):

You can order by the ID, descending, with a rowlimit of 1 in your CAML for the query.

Take a look at my SPServices jQuery library, which will make this much easier. http://SPServices.codeplex.com

BTW, I believe that the list itself contains the last ID, which you can get with GetList. If you want the highest ID shown in a particular view, that won't help, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your SOAP is incorrect, you are missing a "query":

```
<query><Query>...</Query></query>
```